# count most popular value in a group in hive?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am using hive 0.14.0 in a hortonworks data platform, on a big file similar to this input data:

| tpep_pickup_datetime | pulocationid |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-28 23:32:52.0 | 100 |
| 2022-02-28 23:02:40.0 | 202 |
| 2022-02-28 17:22:45.0 | 102 |
| 2022-02-28 23:19:37.0 | 102 |
| 2022-03-29 17:32:02.0 | 102 |
| 2022-01-28 23:32:40.0 | 101 |
| 2022-02-28 17:28:09.0 | 201 |
| 2022-03-28 23:59:54.0 | 100 |
| 2022-02-28 21:02:40.0 | 100 |

I want to find out what was the most common hour in each locationid, this being the result:

| locationid | hour |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 23 |
| 101 | 17 |
| 102 | 17 |
| 201 | 17 |
| 202 | 23 |

Currently I am using this query:

````
      select  pulocationid ,  hour ,  cnt  , row_number () 
      over ( partition by pulocationid order by  cnt desc ) 
      as row_no  from (
            Select pulocationid, hour (tpep_pickup_datetime), count (*) cnt from yellowtaxi22 
            Group by pulocationid, hour (tpep_pickup_datetime) ))
    Where row_no=1 ```

however, this error keeps apearing: 
**FAILED: ParseException line 7:60 cannot recognize input near ')' 'Where' 'row_no' in subquery source**

I have tried to disable the Only_full_group_by, but it says that I can not change it during runtime, is there something esle that I can do?
````

Answer (score 0):

You need alias your inner query. I also fixed some subqry related issues.

````
select  pulocationid ,  hr,  cnt 
From (
select  pulocationid ,  hr,  cnt  , row_number () 
      over ( partition by pulocationid order by  cnt desc ) 
      as row_no  from (
            Select pulocationid, hour (tpep_pickup_datetime) hr, count (*) cnt from yellowtaxi22 
            Group by pulocationid, hour (tpep_pickup_datetime) 
) as rs-- alias the subqry as rs
) Rs2 -- you need to calculate rownum first in inner qry and then call outside.
    Where row_no=1 

```
````